# Change GridViewItem.Width on Window.Current.SizeChanged for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to change the GridViewItem's width property when the window size is changed (Window.Current.SizeChanged) on UWP.

```
    <GridView x:Name="gv" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

I plan to change the GridViewItem's width when the window is resized on windows 10 so that there are no blank spaces on the end.

P.S. image for reference.

Please help.

[image: On resizing the window, there is a blank space that is left]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think change each of GridViewItem's width is a appropriate way.

You can register GridView's `SizeChanged` event. In the event handler, you can get `ItemsWrapGrid` in the GridView, then change ItemsWrapGrid's `ItemWidth` as you want depend on the size of GridView.

```
private void appView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsWrapGrid appItemsPanel = (ItemsWrapGrid)appView.ItemsPanelRoot;

    double optimizedWidth = 140.0;
    double margin = 12.0;
    var number = (int)e.NewSize.Width / (int)optimizedWidth;
    appItemsPanel.ItemWidth = (e.NewSize.Width - margin) / (double)number;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend you change the GridViewItem's width property by using the [AdaptiveTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx), in this way you do not need to handle the Window.Current.SizeChanged event, it will change the GridViewItem's width property automaticly:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyleBig" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyleSmall" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="GridViewWith">
            <VisualState x:Name="MyVisaulState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="gv.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyleBig}"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="MyVisaulState1">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="gv.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyleSmall}"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <GridView x:Name="gv" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Red"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

For more information, please refer to [how to use the AdaptiveTrigger in UWP app](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-adaptivetrigger-to-build-adaptive-uis-in-windows-10).

You can also donwload the sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-AdaptiveTrigger-Sample) about the AdaptiveTrigger.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this before.
But the problem is that here the values for height and width are fixed at 80 or 30 and thus when resizing is done in case of 0< minWindowWidth <800 the width and height remain constant at 30 and thus the empty space/blank space is created.
I would want to to actually increase/decrease the height and width as and when the window is resized.